# Issue with `AND` logical operator mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 columns of interest: `RateName` and `URL`are varchars, `MaxNum` is INT.
When I try to execute the following command, it fails:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `RateName` LIKE '%$customerType%'" AND `URL` IS NOT NULL AND `MaxNum` = 2
```

Error is: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '" AND URL IS NOT NULL AND MaxNumOfTiers = 2' at line 1`

I tried to separate the query, and the following code works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `RateName` LIKE '%$customerType%'"
```

However when I add additional `AND` conditions, I get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove that stray double quote?

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `RateName` LIKE '%$customerType%' -- was here
         AND `URL` IS NOT NULL AND `MaxNum` = 2
```

The one without the extra conditions should fail, unless you have removed it or MySQL ignores it silently

Answer (score 1):

You have extra `"` in your query - remove it and it should work.

In general, avoid using double quote `"` in SQL altogether. Most SQL dialects only support using single quotes. Some dialects, like PostgreSQL, use double quotes to escape names (but not represent strings).

Avoiding double quote in SQL body also has nice property that you can use them to escape whole SQL in your programming language like PHP, Perl, Python, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have the syntax error in your query as you are using ' and " at one place. I have modify it below use that:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `RateName` LIKE '%$customerType%' AND `URL` IS NOT NULL AND `MaxNum` = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try LIKE '%$customerType%' AND instead of LIKE '%$customerType%'" AND and it works fine.